# VHDL assigning values in process depending of falling/rising_edge

Tags: vhdl, fpga

This component is used to detect an external pulse and, based on a specific input (`cs`), choose if it must count on a rising_edge or a falling_edge, but the next problems is displayed:

```
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "contadortemp[7]" at ControlLogic.vhd(46)
Error (10029): Constant driver at ControlLogic.vhd(27)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "contadortemp[6]" at ControlLogic.vhd(46)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "contadortemp[5]" at ControlLogic.vhd(46)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "contadortemp[4]" at ControlLogic.vhd(46)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "contadortemp[3]" at ControlLogic.vhd(46)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "contadortemp[2]" at ControlLogic.vhd(46)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "contadortemp[1]" at ControlLogic.vhd(46)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "contadortemp[0]" at ControlLogic.vhd(46)
```

The problem seems to be the assigment of different values to contadortemp, nevertheless, I can't figure out why. How should I change the assigment logic of `contadortemp` to get the desired performance? Based in the fact that both options should increase the same signal (`contadortemp`) under different circumstances, depending on `cs`

Here's the code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
--use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
--Realiza el conteo y lo reinicia si se llegó al top
entity ControlLogic is
--top: Se activa si se llegó al top (viene de MyTimer)
--clk: Reloj proveido por ClkSelect (pulso externo o prescaler) (viene de MyTimer)

--contador: valor del contador (va a MyTimer)
Port(
    cs: in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    top: in std_logic;
    clk: in std_logic;
    contador: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
);
end ControlLogic;

architecture Behavioral of ControlLogic is

signal contadortemp: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
begin   
    falling_proc : process(clk)
    begin
    if cs = "110" then
        if falling_edge(clk) then
            if (top='0') then
                if contadortemp = "11111111" then
                    contadortemp    <=  (others=>'0');
                else
                    contadortemp    <=  contadortemp + '1';
                end if;
            else
                contadortemp        <=  (others => '0');
            end if;
        end if;
    else
        contadortemp    <= contadortemp;
    end if;
    end process falling_proc;

    rising_proc : process(clk)
    begin
    if cs /= "110" then
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if (top='0') then
                if contadortemp = "11111111" then
                    contadortemp    <=  (others=>'0');
                else
                    contadortemp    <=  contadortemp + '1';
                end if;
            else
                contadortemp        <=  (others => '0');
            end if;
        end if;
    else
        contadortemp    <= contadortemp;
    end if;
    end process rising_proc;

    contador <= contadortemp;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Every process with a signal assignment has a driver for each element of that signal. You have two processes assigning `contadortemp`. That's not allowed by Quartus synthesis, nets may only have a single driver. You essentially have two counters with their outputs tied together.

Comment: Do you have an actual question? (For instance you could ask how to make the counters independent by using separate signals and select between one or the other based on `cs` select which one to assign to output port `contador`).

Comment: The actual question would be: 
what changes should I make to the code in order to get the desired performance? Based in the fact that both options should increase the same signal (`contadortemp`) under different circumstances, depending on `cs`

Comment: You are writing code.   What you need to do is draw a picture of your desired hardware.  Think simple in terms of "multiplexors", "AND", and flip-flops with a single clock edge.  You will need to study the timing of all of the input and output signals.   For example, is "Top" stable on both the falling and rising edge of clock?   Typically inputs are stable for only one edge of clock.   Also you may find that your counter can run on a single edge of clock and simply conditionally get re-clocked by the opposite edge when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The registers in an FPGA can use a rising or falling edge but not both.

Use your clock control block to create a clock running at double the speed of your current clock. Then use a clock enable to count on either the odd or even clock cycles.

```
if rising_edge(fastclock) then
    if (cs = "110" and clk = '1') or (cs /= "110" and clk = '0') then
        -- counter
    end if;
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

merge two processes since they are sensitive to a single signal (clk here).
try using variables more in processes than signals.
after all: think hardware than software. 
try something like this:

```
architecture Behavioral of ControlLogic is

--signal contadortemp: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
begin
   falling_and_rising_edge : process(clk)
    variable contadorVar    : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "00000000";
    begin
    if falling_edge(clk) then
        if cs = "110" then
            if (top='0') then
                if contadorVar  = "11111111" then
                    contadorVar     :=  (others=>'0');
                else
                    contadorVar    :=  contadorVar  + '1';
                end if;
            else
                contadorVar       :=  (others => '0');
            end if;
           contador    <= contadorVar;
        end if;
    end if;
        if rising_edge(clk) then
           if cs /= "110" then
             if (top='0') then
                if contadorVar  = "11111111" then
                    contadorVar    :=  (others=>'0');
                else
                    contadorVar    :=  contadorVar  + '1';
                end if;
             else
                contadorVar      :=  (others => '0');
             end if;
        contador    <= contadorVar; 
       end if;
       end if;
    end process falling_and_rising_edge;
end behavioral;
```

Comment: This goe from having two drivers of the original contadortemp to having two drivers for the output contador.